# how to add data from purchases to stock and subtract data from sales to stock

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Front End Vb 2010
Back End mysql wamp

i have created 3 tables purchases stock and sales.
each table has following coloumns:
id,name,qyt,rate,total.

what i want to do is when i enter a produt in purchases it should automatically be updated in stock table.
and when i sell a product ie enter a product in sales table it should automatically be subtracted from table stock.
also if i sell a product the entire product gets deleted instead only the product quantity should be subtracted.

Currently i know only how to insert and delete data from a single table.
How can the problem be solved.
please help 
thank you in advance

this is how i tried to sell the product

```
MysqlConn.Open()
Dim Query As String
Query = "insert into amrit_traders.sales(date,id,name,qty,rate,amt) values ('" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "')"
Dim que As String = "Delete  from amrit_traders.stock where id='" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND qty='" & TextBox3.Text & "' "
Dim sql As String = Query & que
Command = New MySqlCommand(sql, MysqlConn)
READER = Command.ExecuteReader
MessageBox.Show("Item sold")
MysqlConn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DELETE SQL command is designed to delete an entire record. If you only want to change the contents of a field within a record, then you need to use [UPDATE command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

There are more problems with your code as well.

1. If you have a numeric field, such as qty (quantity), then do not input values as strings. Mysql can silently convert the strings to numbers, but why make it do extra work?
2. If you are issuing data modofication statements, then use ExecuteNonQuery() method because you will not need a reader.
3. You need to make sure that you are not selling more than is in stock. It may be in different part of the code not shown here, I though I would mention it though.
4. You need to make sure that your textboxes contain valid data. Again, it may be in different part of the code not shown here.
5. I would execute the insert and update in 2 separate calls or at least terminate the insert with ";", otherwise MySQL will not know where the insert ends and where the update begins.

Code for update (I'm making the assumption, that textbox3 contains the amount of items you sell, therefore I deduct it from the overall quantity. No checks for stock level, that's something you need to implement if you have not done so):

```
Dim que As String = "UPDATE amrit_traders.stoc set qty=qty-" & TextBox3.Text & " where id='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
```

Comment: how to update products in stock table when i enter them in purchases table